# xslt self closing closing tag add attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some text like,
Input:

> There are two`<Q1/>` candidate objectives`<Q2/>` of common interest:
>   the correct `<Q3/>`

Expected output:

> There are two`<xref ref-type="query" rid="Q0001"/>` candidate
>   objectives`<xref ref-type="query" rid="Q0002"/>` of common interest:
>   the correct `<xref ref-type="query" rid="Q0003"/>`

I have tried the below code,
       it returns only like `<xref ref-type="query" rid="Q0001"/>`

```
<xsl:template match="node()[starts-with(name(),'Q')]">
        <xref ref-type="query">
            <xsl:attribute name="rid">
                <xsl:text>Q</xsl:text><xsl:number format="0000" select="." level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xref>
    </xsl:template>
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the rid attributes in the requested format:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[starts-with(name(),'Q')]">
    <xref ref-type="query">
         <xsl:attribute name="rid">
              <xsl:text>Q</xsl:text><xsl:number format="0001" value="substring-after(name(), 'Q')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xref>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It shows transformation error System ID: KLI.xsl
Scenario: KLI
XSL file: KLI.xsl
XML file: WOCO-380202.xml
Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5
Severity: error
Description: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

System ID: KLI.xsl
Scenario: KLI
XSL file: KLI.xsl
XML file: WOCO-380202.xml
Engine name: Saxon-PE 9.3.0.5
Severity: fatal
Description: The level attribute and value attribute must not both be present
Start location: 93:115
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTSE0975

Comment: Was allowed in xslt 1.0. But simply remove the `level` attribute and it also works in Saxon 9.